# How to get Image(bitmap) from gridView

Tags: android, image, gridview, bitmap

I have gridView that load images from sdcard/dcim/camera and shows them.
I want to put onclick listener on images and when I click on one it shoudl open that picture in other activity. How can I get image from gridView when I click on it.
error is on this line:
intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage()); 
how can I fix this or how else can I make it work ?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    //Create intent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage()); // ERROR IS ON ITEM.GETIMAGE

                    //Start details activity
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();

            String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/DCIM/Camera/";

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

            File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
            for (File file : files){
                myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

    }
```

//*****************************************/

```
public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image ) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

//****************************************************/

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    void add(String path){
        itemList.add(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        return imageView;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        return bm;
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

//***********************************************/

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);

        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

//*******************************************************/

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//*************************************************/

details_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to pass bitmaps between activities.

The logical thing to do would be to pass the image path to the next activity and then decode the image in that activity based on the image view dimensions.

I hope this was helpful. :)